# Lightroom 5. "Convert photo to DNG" then "Save metadata to file"?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, metadata, dng

In my workflow, I import - select - keyword - retouch - rename - and convert .nef photos to .dng. Then I archive all images.

If then I retouch again my dng in the develop module, do I need to 'Ctrl+S' (Save metadata to file) or is it done automatically by Lightroom?

Let's say I [retouch -> convert to dng -> retouch] an image and then send it (but not the catalog) to someone who has Photoshop, will he have the last version of the dng or the version at the time I converted the raw to dng?

Maybe someone who has Photosop could try?

Thank you.

Comment: I am willing to do this comparison for you in PS CS 5.5. if you provide links to test files. :-). Or you can just subscribe for Photoshop CS Trial and do the testing for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightroom does not automatically save those changes to your DNG files. You have to manually press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>. I think that's for performance reasons - storing data in Lightroom catalog is more efficient than saving all changes to individual DNG/xmp/JPEG/TIFF files.

Comment: In catalogue settings, within the section metadata, you can enable "Save changes automatically in xmp". But you have to consider that this will have a performance impact...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to export as DNG to preserve any edits before handing that file off to someone else to edit using Photoshop (ARC).

Comment: I would also suggest that you adjust your workflow just a bit. Instead of converting to DNG so late in the workflow, consider conversion to DNG at time of importing into your Lightroom catalog.

Since LR 4 there have been performance reasons for using DNG: http://goo.gl/rWcpp

Answer (score 0):

All meta data such as tags in Lightroom is stored in the catalogue, not the source images. They are left untouched (Lightroom, by design, is non-destructive - as opposed to Photoshop in which you are working on the live file).

You would need to re-export the .dng to include the new metadata in it.

Comment: That's not entirely true. If you are working with dng files, you can embed the xmp settings into the original file. So you technically change the "original file", but the real image data always remains untouched